# Laravel 5 filter on pivot

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables Candidates & Qualifications with a joining pivot table called Results.

What I want to do is select all candidates for this centre and filter them by a value in the pivot table.

So select all candidates from centre 1 where the pivot “status” = “REGISTERED”

I have tried numerous approaches and am currently with the one below but nothing is working.

```
$candidates = Candidate::where('batch_centre_id','=', $id)->with(array('qualification' => function($q)
{
  $q->wherePivot('status','=', 'REGISTERED');
}))->get();
```

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eloquent **wherePivot** method can only be loaded on a relation. The way you're doing it, you're calling it on **qualifications** relation, therefore you're fetching **all candidates** and then, for each of them, you're loading qualifications that have status=REGISTERED. That's why you're getting **all candidates**.

You could work around it by using Eloquent's **whereHas()** method that let's you filter the base model you're trying to fetch by attributes of some relation. In your case the following should work:

```
$candidates = Candidate::where('batch_centre_id','=', $id)
  ->whereHas('qualifications', function($q) {
    $q->wherePivot('status','=', 'REGISTERED');
  })->with('qualifications')->get();
```

This way you'll get **only candidates that have a qualification with status=REGISTERED** and **all their qualifications**. If you want to additionally filter loaded qualifications by status, add the constraint like you did in your code:

```
$candidates = Candidate::where('batch_centre_id','=', $id)
  ->whereHas('qualifications', function($q) {
    $q->wherePivot('status','=', 'REGISTERED');
  })->with(array('qualifications', function($q) {
    $q->wherePivot('status','=', 'REGISTERED');
  })->get();
```